# Skype (and general) full-screen problems

Tags: 11.10, unity, skype, fullscreen

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 with all updates installed as of now. I am using Unity.

Skype is running more or less OK with one exception. When I have a video call and I try to full-screen the call, the other person's video just hangs. When I go back to windowed mode, the video continues normally.

This only happens when I have another application running in full-screen. When Firefox is running (regardless of whether it is in full-screen or not), Skype full-screen is not possible at all.

Another thing that is possibly related is the playback of video with the default video player. Full-screen just makes the player hang totally. Windowed mode works until a certain window size is reached - after that the player dies. Flash video playback is fine, however.

(**Edit**: Just experimented and mplayer behaves in the same way with full-screen video)

I figure that this is a compiz/unity problem, or something related to the way my video driver plays with unity/compiz. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the suggested video driver to another (still in the suggested drivers list) and that fixed the problems.